# When I change the string into float I always get 0

Tags: php, string

I am trying to convey $string to float. The type of $string is string in the format of "0.0111455667". I have the following code in php.I have tried all these methods and I got 0 for all of them. how can I convert the string to float?why I always get 0?
PS: please do not assume my question as duplicate, I have already tried all the methods in the similar questions and none of them worked for me.

```
            $float = (float) $string;
            //$float2 = $string + 0.0; //this works as well.
            $floatval = floatval($string);
            $double = (double) $string;

            // TEST
            echo $string;
            echo $float;
            //echo $float2;
            echo $floatval;
            echo $double;
```

Comment: I tried your code, can't reproduce your output: https://3v4l.org/pHbNM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the content of `$string`.

In PHP, every time you convert a string to a float, be it by casting `(float) $string`, or `floatval($string)`, you will always get `0` if the first character of the string is not numeric.

From PHP docs: [String conversion to numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero)

Double-check the content of `$string`. Probably you have some spurious characters at its beginning.

Comment: how can I delete the first and second character? the first and second character is " ". It means the whole string is like "0.0098" instead of 0.0098 when I see it in console.

Comment: You can use `$string = trim($string);`. It will remove whitespaces from the beginning and the end of the string.